# React Component requires a unique key prop

Tags: reactjs, key, unique, react-props

I made an create component that renders everything that looks good, but when I do console in browser, it has below error.

> index.js:2178 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have
>   a unique "key" prop.

I tried to have the key props but still has this error. Please see my code below and advise! Thank you very much.

```
    const serviceList = (props) => (

  <CardBody style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${ServiceBgImg})` }}>

    <div>
      <h3 style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}
      >{props.groupName}</h3>
      {props.allServices.filter(groupedServices => groupedServices.category === props.groupName)
        .map(serviceInfo =>
          <List component='nav'>
            <ListItem>
              <ListItemText primary={
                <div key={serviceInfo.id}>
                  <h5  style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                    <span>{serviceInfo.service}</span>
                    <span
                      style={{ float: 'right' }}
                    >{serviceInfo.price}</span>
                  </h5>
                  <h5>
                    {serviceInfo.description}
                  </h5>
                </div>
              }
              />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        )
      }
    </div>

  </CardBody>
);

export default serviceList;
```

Comment: Your `List` should get the key, not your `div` inside the `List`

Answer (score 2):

The outermost/parent element returned by the `map` function needs to have a `key` prop. In your case, it is not the `<div>` but `<List>`, which seems to be a mistake as it seems you wanted to loop over a filtered result of `allServices` to create a list of `serviceInfo`. If that's the case, you should move the map function just above the `<ListItem>` and assign `key` prop to it.

Code example as follow:

```
const serviceList = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h3 style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{props.groupName}</h3>
  <List component='nav'>
  {props.allServices.filter(groupedServices => groupedServices.category === props.groupName).map(serviceInfo =>
    <ListItem key={serviceInfo.id}>
      <ListItemText primary={
         <div key={serviceInfo.id}>
           <h5 style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
             <span>{serviceInfo.service}</span>
             <span
               style={{ float: 'right' }}
             >{serviceInfo.price}</span>
           </h5>
           <h5>{serviceInfo.description}</h5>
        </div>
       }/>
   </ListItem>)}
 </List>

</div>);
export default serviceList;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your List component should wrap the map function, and inside that you add the key to mapped ListItems:

```
<List component='nav'>
...
.map((serviceInfo, index) =>
    <ListItem key={index}>
      ...
    </ListItem>
    ....
```